# React - State update with event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I have a component which connects to websocket over stomp, using the following code:

```
stompClient.current.connect(
                headers,
                () => {
                    const url = `topic/url`;
                    stompClient.current.subscribe(url, (payload) => {
                        onEventReceived(payload);
                    });
                },
                onError
            );
```

onEventReceived:

```
const onEventReceived = (payload) => {
        const newMessage = JSON.parse(payload.body);
        console.log('received message', newMessage);
        console.log('all messages', transcriptMessages);
        if (newMessage.isPartial) {
            if (!transcriptMessages.length) {
                setTranscriptMessages([newMessage]);
                return;
            }
            const messageIndex = transcriptMessages.findIndex((message) => message.uuid === newMessage.uuid);                transcriptMessages[messageIndex] = newMessage;
            setTranscriptMessages([...transcriptMessages]);
        }
        setTranscriptMessages([newMessage, ...transcriptMessages]);

    };
```

The problem:
the output of 'all messages' console is always an empty array.
I think to react state changes do not reflect in my websocket event listener. Any idea how I can composite my component to reflect the state changes into the event listener callback?

Comment: I think you are facing a stale closure problem. You could update your state using an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) `setTranscriptMessages(messages => [newMessage, ...messages])`.

Unfortunately I don't know how to fix the part related to the message being partial, but maybe an updater function with all the logic will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `transcriptMessages` variable is closure-captured. Another thing to keep in mind is due to state updates are not happening immediately, calling `setTranscriptMessages` will not update `transcriptMessages` immediately, only on next render.

You should use [functional update](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```
const onEventReceived = (payload) => {
  const newMessage = JSON.parse(payload.body);
  console.log("received message", newMessage);
  setTranscriptMessages((curr) => {
    console.log('all messages', curr);
    if (newMessage.isPartial) {
      if (!curr.length) {
        return [newMessage];
      }
      const messageIndex = curr.findIndex(
        (message) => message.uuid === newMessage.uuid
      );
      curr[messageIndex] = newMessage;
      return [...curr];
    } else {
      return [newMessage, ...curr];
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Awesome! I actually tried it but wrapped only a part of it (oops)